# Button is clicked but program crashes selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, button, selenium-webdriver

```html
<div class="post-info-tumblelogs">
<div class="post-info-post-tumblelog">
<div class="post-info-tumblelog">
<a class="follow_link worded-follow-button" data-subview="follow" href="/follow/iglovequotes">
<div class="follow-text" title="Follow">Follow</div>
<div class="unfollow-text" title="Unfollow">Unfollow</div>
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

```js
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
   withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
   build();
driver.manage().window().maximize();


driver.get('https://www.tumblr.com/login');
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('signup_email')).sendKeys('username');
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('signup_password')).sendKeys('password');
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('signup_forms_submit')).click();

driver.get('https://www.tumblr.com/search/tv+series');


/*  THIS PART IS FOR FOLLOW
driver.wait(function(){
  var followButton = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/article[3]/header/div/div/div/a/div[1][@class='follow-text']"));
  followButton.click();
},3000);
*/

// THIS PART IS FOR LOVE BUTTON
driver.wait(function(){
  var followButton = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/article[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[@class='post_control like']"));
  followButton.click();
},3000);



driver.quit();
```

I use selenium webdriver with javascript. In this code, I'm trying to click to a follow button and love button in the tumblr page but after clicking to the button, it gives an error and does not follow the next action,It crashes. Errors for follow and love buttons are like this:

```js
goog.global.setTimeout(function() { throw exception; }, 0);
                                      ^
NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/article[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[@class='post_control like']"}
```

```js
UnknownError: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (934, 590). Other element would receive the click: <div class="unfollow-text" title="Unfollow">...</div>
```

First error is for love button, second error is for follow button. What can I do to fix this problem? in both actions, it succeeds and buttons are clicked but the error prevents me to do another action in the same code. I'm waiting for your help.

Comment: Include a sample of html

Comment: I added a HTML code for the follow part. I guess the reason is that follow and unfollow buttons are in same place and when it clicks follow button, it becomes unfollow button and it causes a crash in the code. What can I do to fix that ?

Answer (score 1):

You are using absolute xpath

Try something like this:-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@title='Unfollow']"));
```

It will be helpful if you have posted your full HTML code or page link here so we can help you more accurately.

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: I could post the full page but it is more than 1700 lines. But basically as you can see in the code, it is a search result page in tumblr. By the way, what do you mean by giving absolute xpath? Is it something wrong to do?

Comment: I changed it with that:     var followButton = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath("//article[2]/header/div/div/div/a/div[1][@class='follow-text']"));   Again, it clicks to button but gives the same error and crashes. I guess it tries to click it again and therefore error occurs. How can I prevent this problem?

Comment: I guess reason of the problem was wait method, I just cancelled waiting and directly did the actions, now it is working. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that tumblr does a/b testing too. username and password could be asked in either one step or two steps, so the webdriver maybe couldn't find the correct element on the page.